# Add like box to header of my app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

Does anyone know how to add "like box" container to header of my application like [here](https://www.facebook.com/cocacola?v=app_161193133389)?
This one:

[image]

Comment: [well, i found, answer is here](http://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/26330/How-to-Create-Custom-Tabs-for-Facebook-Business-Pages.aspx)..

Comment: well, maybe does someone know how to add event subscribe to that like button in the right?

"edge.create" works only with buttons which i added by myself, like (<fb:like></fb:like>)

Comment: Maybe make some research before you ask question? This is not google...

Answer (score -1):

There you can find all tools and api which facebook offer for developers:

http://developers.facebook.com/

Likebox is there too.

Answer (score -2):

here is official [facebook info](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). There is also code around to enable more social media sites like [this](http://www.addthis.com/blog/2011/08/19/facebook-like-twitter-tweet-google-1-get-them-all-using-addthis/#.T_03w1DdGRs).

Comment: @Mateusz Rogulski, Your answer is not exact, also I provide him with an additional option. btw when I opened the question your answer was not there and I delayed my answer a few minutes for other doing.. if I saw your answer I would perhaps edit it. When I submitted answer Isaw it but it is vague so left mine in. Anyways I don't think your -1 is appropriate but shame on you. I am wondering who the second -1 is from, I can't see any reason for that. btw I did not vote down your answer, it was somebody else.